# How to join four table for invoice?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, join, invoice

I have to issue a sales invoice was created four tables:(to send variable in stimulsoft)

How do I use the procedure for joining these tables together?

these are the tables :

[image]

this is the procedure :

```js
USE [RahgoshafanDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Invoice_Soft] Script Date: 05/19/2015 10:30:26 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[Invoice_Soft]
@Invoice_Id int

AS
BEGIN
select
       dbo.Customer.Customer as customer,
       dbo.Customer.Tel as tel,
       dbo.Customer.Adr as adr,
       dbo.Software_Invoice.Dat as dat,
       dbo.Software_Invoice.Payable as payable,
       dbo.Software_Invoice.Discount as discount,
       dbo.Software.Software as software,
       dbo.Software_Order.Price as price,
       dbo.Software_Order.Quantity as quantity,
       dbo.Software_Order.Sum as sum
       From dbo.Software_Invoice inner join dbo.Customer 
       on dbo.Software_Invoice.Customer_Id = dbo.Customer.Id  AND     
       dbo.Software_Invoice.Id = dbo.Software_Order.Invoice_Id   
       where  dbo.Software_Invoice.Id = @Invoice_Id
END
```

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are missing two `JOIN`-statements:

```
FROM dbo.Software_Invoice
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customer 
        ON dbo.Software_Invoice.Customer_Id = dbo.Customer.Id
    INNER JOIN dbo.Software_Order     
        ON dbo.Software_Invoice.Id = dbo.Software_Order.Invoice_Id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Software
        ON dbo.Software_Order.Software_Id = dbo.Software.Id
```

This should probably fix it.

**Explanation**

When using SQL JOIN, you are joining what you have now with a new table. So joining two tables, you will use

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table1]
INNER JOIN [Table2]
    ON [Table1].[ForeignKeyToTable2] = [Table2].[PrimaryKey]
```

The `ON` part can be any condition, not necessarily foreign key relationships.

After these two tables have been joined, you now have a new "table" consisting of all columns of the two tables (`[Table1].*` and `[Table2].*`). This can then further be joined with a new `JOIN` statement:

```
INNER JOIN [Table3]
    ON [Table3].[Column] = [Table1/2].[Column]
```

The `ON` statement can further consist of several conditionals, e.g.,:

```
ON [Table3].[Column1] = [Table1].[Column1]
    AND [Table3].[Column2] = [Table2].[Column1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `INNER JOIN`.
Please add

```
INNER JOIN dbo.Software_Order ON dbo.Software_Invoice.Id = dbo.Software_Order.Invoice_Id
```

Good luck.

Comment: ...And @Njål is correct, if you want to include `Software.Software` in your select, you have one more `INNER JOIN` to perform.